# docker wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: windows, docker, connection, firewall

docker build error:  wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Windows 10, latest docker version. ALL WINDOWS FIREWALLS ARE SWITCHED OFF. What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me.

`Docker tray icon > settings > general > enable > expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`

[image: Screenshot]

Then add this to your `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`

```
{
"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
}
```

Restart docker/windows.

More info at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

Comment: No luck using this method for me. I got errors when trying to start up Docker. My `daemon.json` was also at `C:\Users\<user name>\.docker\daemon.json`